# Remove phone Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently testing with different selfbots on Discord.py. I wanted to know if there was a way to remove the phone number off my account. I tried `bot.remove_phone` but that didnt work. I am completely new to python.

Answer (score 1):

### Self botting is against the Terms and Service of Discord.

Moreover, Discord doesn't give out features to further hurt their platform by their API. If Discord happens to detect this your account would be banned. Either way, `remove_phone` attribute is not included in the Official Discord documentation.

But for clarity, anything considered "user account automation" is disallowed, including custom clients and similar.
Here's Discord's reference:

https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Comment: Yes im familiar with the concept, is there not a way to do it, regardless?

Answer (score 1):

I cant make an comment so I have to make an answer, but you could make an `requests.delete()` to discord, you need the token and its password.
You can find more info about how the request should look like by being logged in discord via chrome, then open dev tools with `ctrl + i -> go to network and select XHR` then you can try and delete phone number with a wrong password to get an idea how the request should look like

also probably should not use your main since you might do couple mistakes and lose your account